# ng-model value undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got undefined inside my ng-model. I already defined inside my controller. `$scope.rule.message` no issue but for `$scope.rule.ruleId` got undefined.

html

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Group</label> <select ng-model="rule.ruleId" ng-repeat="rule in rules">
            <option value="{{rule.ruleId}}">
                #{{rule.keyword}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Message</label> 

        <textarea class="form-control" cols="" name="" rows="" ng-model="rule.message">
</textarea>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" ng-click="create()">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

js

```
mzsmsControllers.controller('MemberBlastCreateCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
    '$location',
    function($scope, $http, $location) {
        $scope.rule = {};
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://example.com/get_all_rules.php?fbId=' + sessionStorage.id
        }).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.rules = data.rules;
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("No internet connection.");
        });
        $scope.create = function() {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://example.com/create_blast.php?fbId=' + sessionStorage.id +
                    '&ruleId=' + $scope.rule.ruleId + '&message=' + $scope.rule.message
            }).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                alert("SMS Blast successfuly created.");
                $location.path("/member/blast");
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("No internet connection.");
            });
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: can you print out `data.rules`?

Comment: You want multiple `select`s with a single `option`?

Comment: [$scope.rules = data.rules;], [$scope.rules] is called but [$scope.rule] is never called???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that ng-repeat creates a new scope, try changing the ng-repeat:

```
<select ng-model="rule.ruleId" ng-repeat="r in rules">
        <option value="{{r.ruleId}}">
            #{{r.keyword}}
        </option>
    </select>
```